# how to add roles to my users in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, roles

I have a simple app with an authentication system from devise. I tried adding roles to the user model. But nothing happens.

what i did was
**created the Role model and link it to the User Model:**

```
$ rails g model Role name:string
$ rails g migration addRoleIdToUser role:references
$ rake db:migrate
```

(as directed by the devise wiki)

**Then in my Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
end
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

**Set up seeds.rb with my roles:**

```
['seller', 'buyer', 'admin'].each do |role|
  Role.find_or_create_by({name: role})
end
```

**Then**

```
$ rake db:seed
```

That's all. And I also want to know how to make the user chose any of these roles at the time of signup

Answer (score 17):

First of all, instead of using an association, you can use `enum` in your user class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
   enum role: {seller: 0, buyer: 1, admin: 2}

   ... 
end
```

You'll need a migration to add a `role` (integer) column into your user's table.

In your terminal:

```
rails g migration add_role_to_users
```

Then edit the migration file:

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :users, :role, :integer
   end
end
```

Then you can e.g. use the [`SimpleForm` gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to let the user choose his/her role during sign up:

```
<%=  simple_for for @user do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a %>
   ... 
<% end %>
```

But SimpleForm is also good with associations:

```
<%= f.association :role, as: :radio_buttons %>
```

There are more examples for associations [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations).

Comment: hey @zhurora sorry for this stupid question but can can u pls tell me what migration do i need

Comment: I added the migration. Feel free to edit the answer, when you find any errors while using it, since I haven't check my code.

Comment: Hey @zhurora thank you very much every thing just worked perfectly but there is one problem when i checked my console its saying that role id is nil i want to use cancancan now and for that i have to associate role id with user can u help me

Comment: Cancancan shouldn't force you into how you want to manage your roles (through enum or association). Watch [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) RailsCast and you should be able to use Cancancan afterwards.

Comment: means not important to make the role id associated with the users right....right now it showing role id nil in console...is it ok? @zhurora

Comment: What did you end up using - enum or association? If you are using association (`has_may :roles`), then `:role_id` should be set for every user. If you are using `enum role:`, then you can us `some_user.role` or `some_user[:role]`.

Comment: am using enum how to set `some_user[:role]` @zhurora please

Comment: It's better to user: `enum roles: [:seller, :buyer, :admin]`, and `<%= f.select :role, User.roles %>`

Answer (score 3):

While you can add roles to your application like the way you did. But, it would be a lot of work to handle all types of roles and their responsibilities. Also,
There are several nice gems like [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) and [cancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) which can be used to handle the authorization for your application users. They're very easy to integrate with your Rails application and works nicely with authentication gem [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) which you are already using.

Here is a nice [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qruGD_8ry7k) which shows Rails Authorization with Pundit.