# Role is not being added to users in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, roles

I've been having issues creating separate users for my rails web application. Today I tried to follow Zhurora's answer to a similar post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159123

However now when users are signing up on the signup page, and select a role from the options, that role does not get written into the database. I had set up the migrations as instructed and when I check the schema it has an entry for role.

However it still doesnt get added. This is what happens in the terminal when a user signs up after selecting a role.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-07 19:54:54 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"XKuxBEDRnYGOMMJXP1hb8HfkHkVc4WrMddq13WCqnXW//g6R+yzZ7DB8NTBkDgKsJReIcg83gkmfYaTEpmq+iQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"gdfgdfg", "email"=>"Mytest@Mytest.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "role"=>"restaurant"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: :role
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "mytest@mytest.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "gdfgdfg"], ["email", "mytest@mytest.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$4qjIxrh1RO.CL7FEPoVFs.xa712fALq4ayFMIC/8taGmU6iUWRphe"], ["created_at", "2018-04-07 17:54:54.479270"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-07 17:54:54.479270"]]
(428.6ms)  COMMIT
```

**And here is my user.rb model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

enum role: {person: 0, restaurant: 1, admin: 2}

has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

validates :role, presence: true
validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

end
```

**My schema.rb file with the user table**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "name", default: "", null: false
   t.string "email", default: "", null: false
   t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
   t.string "reset_password_token"
   t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
   t.datetime "remember_created_at"
   t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
   t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
   t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
   t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
   t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.integer "role"
   t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
   t.index ["reset_password_token"], name:   "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

**The migration file**

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end
```

**And my signup html.erb page**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_field :name,
                           placeholder: 'username (will be shown publicly)',
                           class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.text_field :email,
                           placeholder: 'email',
                           class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password,
                              placeholder: 'password',
                              class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,
                              placeholder: 'password confirmation',
                              class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a %>

        <%= f.submit 'Sign up', class: 'btn sign-up-button' %>
      <% end %>
```

In my attempt to fix it, I have dropped all the tables, thinking it wasnt getting updated in postgresql properly. 
Recreated the tables and run the migrations through again. 
I have also deleted the schema file and ran the migrations again generating a new schema file.

None of that has worked.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to permit additional parameters

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
  end
end
```

Comment: I added it now, but I still seem to be getting the same issue. I tried resetting the db again as well. Yet still did not work

Comment: Nevermind.. I've been very blind and stupid. You were right, I just needed to define it in a different controller

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mezbah I looked into adding role to the permitted parameters.

I was blinded and overlooked that.

I overrided the registrations controller with my own

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit( :name,
                                :email,
                                :password, 
                                :password_confirmation)

    end

    def account_update_params
     params.require(:user).permit( :name,
                                :email,
                                :password,
                                :password_confirmation,
                                :current_password)
   end
 end
```

This is how it looked before.

And based on what Mezbah said, I added it to here

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 private

def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit( :name,
                                :email,
                                :password, 
                                :password_confirmation,
                                :role)
end

def account_update_params
  params.require(:user).permit( :name,
                                :email,
                                :password,
                                :password_confirmation,
                                :current_password)
end
```

end

And now it works :D

Here is a successful entry into the database

```
 Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-07 22:45:24 +0200
 Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ccL1AgCfT8WfRv7ObfF3INJ8bNcpQ1/WVDBxtX3CAUAW1Qsq+T3ndoYGMikOgrkWuUZmA9vtv2FS70+zTnwzmw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"MyTest", "email"=>"Mytest@Mytest.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "role"=>"restaurant"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "mytest@mytest.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "role") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "MyTest"], ["email", "mytest@mytest.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$isG5sdUAJmmtKCcgt4oZ1.HP6IPT4F2oPOFWWMi.raYJLsbuhcnPC"], ["created_at", "2018-04-07 20:45:24.216616"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-07 20:45:24.216616"], ["role", 1]]
    (19.3ms)  COMMIT
```